PXE does not make dhcp request
I was experimenting with DRBL. In order to do it, I've created two virtual machine in VMWare Workstation.
The two virtual machines are connected together by a virtual private network, host only, with dhcp disabled. It should be like I connect the two VMs directly with a network cable.
In order to install drbl, I've performed following steps:

Installed the Ubuntu Server 24.04
Run the following command for adding the drbl repository: sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://free.nchc.org.tw/drbl-core drbl stable'
Updated the repository by making it trusted with deb [trusted=yes] http://free.nchc.org.tw/drbl-core drbl stable.
Update the server with apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
Install drbl with sudo apt-get install drbl

Then in order to configure the service, I've performed following steps:

Configured drbl with sudo drblsrv -i
Updated the /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf file with following content:

# option domain-name "example.org";
# option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

subnet 192.168.209.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.209.10 192.168.209.150;
option routers 192.168.209.1;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 192.168.209.255;
}


I've updated the /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server file by adding INTERFACES="ens37" that's the network interface of the server connected to the private network.
I've configured the network interface of the server by updating the /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml file:

network:
    ethernets:
        ens33:
            dhcp4: true
        ens37:
            dhcp4: false
            ignore-carrier: true
            addresses:
            - 192.168.209.1/24
            routes:
            - to: default
              via: 192.168.209.1
    version: 2


Restarted the dhcpd server with

sudo service isc-dhcp-server restart


Updated the /etc/yp.conf file with the ip of the server:

ypserver 192.168.209.1


Started drbl with sudo drbl-all-service start

Now, when I start the client virtual machine, I can see that it receives the address and its network interface it's correctly configured. In the log of the dhcp I can see:
Oct 30 16:29:06 backupserver dhcpd[7483]: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:50:56:35:26:63 (testdrbl-vmwarevirtualplatform) via ens37
Oct 30 16:29:06 backupserver dhcpd[7483]: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.209.12 to 00:50:56:35:26:63 (testdrbl-vmwarevirtualplatform) via ens37
Oct 30 16:29:06 backupserver dhcpd[7483]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.209.12 (192.168.209.1) from 00:50:56:35:26:63 (testdrbl-vmwarevirtualplatform) via ens37
Oct 30 16:29:06 backupserver dhcpd[7483]: DHCPACK on 192.168.209.12 to 00:50:56:35:26:63 (testdrbl-vmwarevirtualplatform) via ens37

Instead, when I restart the client by activating PXE at boot time, it remains stuck at the DHCP line, and in the server I can see following log:
Oct 30 16:30:29 backupserver dhcpd[7483]: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:50:56:35:26:63 via ens37
Oct 30 16:30:30 backupserver dhcpd[7483]: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.209.13 to 00:50:56:35:26:63 via ens37
Oct 30 16:30:31 backupserver dhcpd[7483]: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:50:56:35:26:63 via ens37
Oct 30 16:30:31 backupserver dhcpd[7483]: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.209.13 to 00:50:56:35:26:63 via ens37
Oct 30 16:30:35 backupserver dhcpd[7483]: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:50:56:35:26:63 via ens37
Oct 30 16:30:35 backupserver dhcpd[7483]: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.209.13 to 00:50:56:35:26:63 via ens37
Oct 30 16:30:43 backupserver dhcpd[7483]: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:50:56:35:26:63 via ens37
Oct 30 16:30:43 backupserver dhcpd[7483]: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.209.13 to 00:50:56:35:26:63 via ens37

Basically it seems that the client does not send the DHCPREQUEST command, but since it works with the normal boot I'm not sure that's a mistake in the VMware network configuration. I think that it can be a problem of the configuration of DHCP.
What I'm doing wrong? How can I set up the dhcp server in order to work also with PXE?

If you want to PXE boot your DHCP server not only has to provide an IP but also the PXE info; basically the TFTP router IP and the NBP.
In your case the PXE client boots up, only receives an IP and it cannot continue
restarting the DORA sequence in a loop.
The client screen should tell you it cannot find the TFTP server or missing NBP or things like that.
